# find smallest and largest element in array and print location of element

Tags: java, arrays

What is the easiest way to find the largest and smallest element in an array and print its index location without using an algorithm. Is there a way to do it using a loop or if statement as i am new to java and it is as far as my knowledge goes for now.

This is my code for the array:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Tut2ArraysQ4
{

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
{
 BufferedReader kbd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

int []item=new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
            int num=Integer.parseInt(kbd.readLine());
            System.out.println("Index " + i + " Contains Number "     + num);
        }

}//end class
}//end main
```

i am grateful for your help

Comment: To make this line `System.out.println("Index " + i + " Contains Number " + num);` true you have to insert `item[i] = num;` before it. Finding min and max can be done one single loop.

Comment: "___without using an algorithm___" ??

Comment: Also, read about what an [Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) is!

Answer (score 2):

You declare two variables equal to the element in the first position of your array, and two equal to the first position.

```
int min = array[0];
int max = array[0];
int posMin = 0;
int posMax = 0;
```

Make a for to iteration over all position of the array:

```
   for(all the position of the array)
      // if current position bigger than max
         // max = element of the array in the current position
         // posMin = current position
     // if current position smaller than min
        // min = element of the array in the current position
        // posMax = current position
```

Another approach is sorting the array, the smallest element will be in the first position and the biggest on the last position of the array. However, this solution takes typically `N lg N` while the first one I post performance in `N`. If you are using radix sort it will take k N, but:

> Sometimes k is presented as a constant, which would make radix sort
>   better (for sufficiently large n) than the best comparison-based
>   sorting algorithms, which are all O(n·log(n)). However, in general k
>   cannot be considered a constant.

read more [about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but unfortunately, There is no way to do what you're trying to do without using an Algorithm.

Even if you pick 2 numbers and prey that you're right, you'll be using an algorithm.